# How to move from Java EE to OpenJDK?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using:

- Java EE 1.8
- Eclipse 2022-12
- Apache Tomcat v10.1.1

I would like to move to OpenJDK. How do I replace the Java EE 1.8 with the OpenJDK in Eclipse please?

Comment: Just install an OpenJDK JDK and use that to build and run your code. What difficulty are you having exactly?

Comment: Java EE (as it used to be called) doesn't depend on the Java SE version.  And OpenJDK doesn't replace Java EE in any sense.

Comment: OpenJDK is Java SE implementation not Java EE. For Java EE you would need an application server, so you can't simply replace it.

Comment: @StephenC I obviously do not know enough about this. Can you please direct me to some readings please?

Comment: @Pavel I obviously do not know enough about this. Can you please direct me to some readings please?

Comment: @Glyn Wikipedia is often a good place to start your research.

Answer (score 2):

[Java SE (Standard Edition)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition) is a set of [specifications](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_(technical_standard)) published by [Oracle Corp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation). See [*Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Several vendors release software implementing those specifications. These vendors include, in no specific order: Amazon, BellSoft, IBM, Oracle, SAP, Azul Systems, Microsoft, Red Hat, and more.

Nearly all of these implementations are built largely, if not entirely, from the source code housed at the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) open-source project. That project is owned by Oracle Corp. Others contribute code and labor, including IBM, Apple, and more.

Oracle also owned a set of specifications for software to run on top of Java SE implementations. These specs were known as *Java Enterprise Edition (Java EE)* because they were aimed primarily at enterprise-oriented developers. Oracle in recent years donated these specs and related technologies to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation), where they were open-sourced. The name changed to [*Jakarta EE*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE).

Several vendors publish software that implement the Jakarta EE specs. Some of these vendors publish app server software that bundle several of the Jakarta EE implementations to form a deployment container for your app that uses these Jakarta EE technologies.

[*Apache Tomcat*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) is one such product that provides implementations of several Jakarta EE specs in a web app deployment container. These implemented specs include [*Jakarta Servlet*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet), [*Jakarta Server Pages*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages), [*Jakarta Expression Language*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Expression_Language), and more.

The Eclipse Foundation also publishes a popular [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). The IDE is known simply as [*Eclipse*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)). You can use Eclipse to write Java-based apps.  These apps can optionally use libraries that implement some of the Jakarta EE specs.

So your Question does not make any sense.

- Eclipse is an IDE used to write Java-based apps.
- Your app written in Eclipse can use any of several implementations of Java, nearly all of which are based on the source-code published by the OpenJDK project.
- Java-based apps can optionally make use of libraries implementing Jakarta EE specs.
- If using those Jakarta EE technologies, you’ll need a [container app server](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) in which to deploy your app. Tomcat is one such container.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution :

Window → Preferences → Java → Installed JREs → Add [Here add your open JDK path]